# What is the meter of this verse from the Panchatantra?

Tags: sanskrit, verse

This is the verse:

मनवे वाचस्पतये शुक्राय पराशराय ससुताय ।
चाणक्याय च विदुषे नमोऽस्तु नयशास्त्रकर्तृभ्यः ॥

I'm not able to figure out which meter this verse was written in. Would appreciate some details on the meter as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's not written in any single meter. The first section can be taken to be Pamkti Chhandas since it has 20 syllables, but, the second has 18 which would turn it into Brhati Chhandas.

म1न2वे3 वा4च5स्प6त7ये8 शु9क्रा10

य1 प2रा3श4रा5य6 स7सु8ता9य10 ।

चा1ण2क्या3य4 च5 वि6दु7षे8 न9

मो1ऽस्तु2 न3य4शा5स्त्र6क7र्तृ8भ्यः9 ॥

Anyways, this is written in the introduction to the actual content, this is semi-common to not have properly poetic verses in the beginning, since them being remembered or not properly isn't relevant (unlike the content).

In this case, it is still a Shloka but, it's just in two Chhandas.

As for correct pronunciation, it's complicated, but just try to make 10 and 9 syllables 'flow', respectively and you'll get a mostly functioning, correct pronunciation. The important part is that it's nice and rythimic to listen to, so it can be remembered easily rather than what is correct in terms of the Vedaanga.